# OpenCV findContours causes Debug Assertion Failed at return

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv

I am programming on Visual Studio 2013, using OpenCV v 2.4.8.
Here is my code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1], 0);
    image = image > 100;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(image, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything is Ok in release mode, and I can't understand why it doesn't work normal in debug mode. It causes debug assertion failed at `return 0;`

> (Expression : _pFirstBlock == pHead).

I suppose something is wrong with contours.

Many thanks in assistance.

Comment: if to add `cv::imshow("img", image);` before `return 0;` there is no debug fail.

Comment: On Visual Studio 2012 everything is Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Under Property > C++ > code generation > Runtime libarary:
If the MSVC Runtime library is set to Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd), then this is no problem (it works fine).

If the MSVC Runtime library is set to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd), then it will throw this error, which can be fixed with the following instructions.

Comment: I am using /MDd, but i have such problem. If I set /MTd it won't be even compiled. @Surinder, what version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2012

Comment: On Visual Studio 2012 everything is Ok. Heap Error occurs only on Visual Studio 2013.