# findContours returns assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv, assertion

Seems that the findContours function has been returning some assertion fails with Visual Studios C++ 2012.  I've made sure that all my include directories were fine.

```
void track (Mat input_video, Mat &output_video)
    {
    Mat temp;
    input_video.copyTo(temp);
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    //Only search through the most external layer.
    for (int i=0; i>=0; i=hierarchy[i][0])
    {

        Moments moment = moments((Mat) contours[i]);
        double area= moment.m00;
        double xmc= moment.m10;
        double ymc= moment.m01;
        double x= xmc/area;
        double y= ymc/area;
        circle(output_video, Point(x,y), 3, Scalar(0,255,255));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The rest of my code if you may need it:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//This function threshold the HSV image and create a binary image
Mat GetThresholdedImage(Mat imgHSV, int huemin, int satmin, int valmin, int huemax, int satmax, int valmax)
{
    //Size s= imgHSV->size();
    Mat imgThresh(imgHSV.size().height, imgHSV.size().width, CV_8U);
    //returns matrix that contains all values within the given HSV range.
    inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(huemin,satmin,valmin), Scalar(huemax,satmax,valmax), imgThresh); 
       return imgThresh;
}

Mat morph(Mat imgThresh)
{
    Mat erode_element= getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3));
    Mat dilate_element= getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(8,8));

    erode(imgThresh, imgThresh, erode_element);
    erode(imgThresh, imgThresh, erode_element);
    dilate(imgThresh, imgThresh, dilate_element);

    return imgThresh;
}

void track (Mat input_video, Mat &output_video)
{
    Mat temp;
    input_video.copyTo(temp);
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    cerr<< contours.size();
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    cerr<<contours.size();
    //Only search through the most external layer.
    for (int i=0; i>=0; i=hierarchy[i][0])
    {

        Moments moment = moments((Mat) contours[i]);
        double area= moment.m00;
        double xmc= moment.m10;
        double ymc= moment.m01;
        double x= xmc/area;
        double y= ymc/area;
        circle(output_video, Point(x,y), 3, Scalar(0,255,255));
    }
}


int main()
{
    VideoCapture capture(0);
    if(!capture.isOpened()){
        cerr<< "Capture failed";
        return -1;
      }

    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("Original");      
    namedWindow("Binary");
    //Create slider for adjustments...
    namedWindow("Adjustments");
    int huemin= 0, satmin= 0, valmin= 0;
    int huemax= 256, satmax= 256, valmax= 256;
    createTrackbar("Min Hue", "Adjustments", &huemin, 256);
    createTrackbar("Max Hue", "Adjustments", &huemax, 256);
    createTrackbar("Min Saturation", "Adjustments", &satmin, 256);
    createTrackbar("Max Saturation", "Adjustments", &satmax, 256);
    createTrackbar("Min Value", "Adjustments", &valmin, 256);
    createTrackbar("Max Value", "Adjustments", &valmax, 256);
      //iterate through each frames of the video      
    while(true)
    {
        //Grabs each frame from video to be processed.
        capture>> frame;
        //Error checks and breaks if the grab failed.
        if(!frame.data)
            {
                cerr<< "Failed to grab frame\n";
                break;
            }

        //Apply a Gaussian Blur kernel.
        //GaussianBlur(frame, frame, Size(3,3), 3, 3, 4);
        Mat imgHSV(frame.size(), CV_8UC3);
        cvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV, 0); //Change the color format from BGR to HSV
        Mat imgThresh = GetThresholdedImage(imgHSV, huemin, satmin, valmin, huemax, satmax, valmax);
        //GaussianBlur(imgThresh, imgThresh, Size(5,5), 3, 3, 4); //smooth the binary image using Gaussian kernel
        imgThresh= morph(imgThresh);
        track(imgThresh, frame);
        imshow("Binary", imgThresh);  
        imshow("Original", frame);

        int key = waitKey(30);
        //If 'ESC' is pressed, break the loop
        if(key==27 ) break;      
      }

    destroyAllWindows();
      //cvReleaseCapture(&capture);     

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: please, the *exact* assertion that failed ..

Comment: @Eugene Laksana Before accessing contour just  check, contour is there or not by contours.size()...

Comment: @berak _pFirstBlock==pHead

Comment: @Haris, the size returned 0.  Yes, contour is there

Comment: @EugeneLaksana If size return 0, that means number of contour 0.

Comment: @Haris Isn't contour an output vector of vectors, though?  Wouldn't it be filled via the function?  Also, I just called contour.size() after the function, and it returned 1...

Comment: I have also commented out the for loop, and the program still returns the assertion error.  It only disappears after I comment out the findCounters function.

Comment: @EugeneLaksana Make sure that your are passing single channel 8 bit image to findcontour.

Comment: your loop is strange... `for (int i=0; i>=0; i=hierarchy[i][0])` are your sure that there is a negative value in `hierarchy[i][0]`? maybe there is a big value inside which is bigger than the size of hierarchy and so you try to access `hierarchy[tooBig]` in the second run? Why is there a loop after all if you just want to use the most external contour?

Comment: @Micka there is a negative value when the number of elements in the same hierarchy expires. The loop isn't the problem, though.  Even after commenting it out, the assertion failure still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene, I encountered the same problem. try to add "cv::imshow("im", output_video);"
as mentioned in - [OpenCV findContours causes Debug Assertion Failed at return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809784/opencv-findcontours-causes-debug-assertion-failed-at-return)